# Table body columns not coming properly using Google Cloud Vision API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

I parsed a JPG image using [API version v1](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest) and got the tables. But when tried to read a table using Google Vision the output has first 2 columns combined. The screenshot of table can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFOgb.png).
Response is shown below ->

```
array:146 [▼
  0 => "Ln#"
  1 => "Item"
  2 => "HSN/SAC Code"
  3 => "Hazardous"
  4 => "Qty"
  5 => "Unit Price"
  6 => "Disc."
  7 => "Tax Description"
  8 => "Sub Total"
  9 => "0 1670940-00"
  10 => "853190"
  11 => "No"
  12 => "200.00"
  13 => "IGST@18 (18.00%)"
  14 => "1,000.00"
  15 => "Hinged Cover for HCP/CCP Range (PS200)"
```

As seen above in the 9th index, "0 1670940-00" are coming combined. They should be in separate indexes.

It's happening only for rows having more than 1 lines. The Google Vision API client code is as below.

```
$request = new AnnotateImageRequest();
$request->setImage($image);
$request->setFeature("TEXT_DETECTION");
$gcvRequest = new GoogleCloudVision([$request],  env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEY'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran some test using the image you shared, and I found that the issue as described is resolved by using the feature ["DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22requests%22%3A%5B%7B%22features%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION%22%7D%5D%2C%22image%22%3A%7B%22source%22%3A%7B%22imageUri%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FpFOgb.png%22%7D%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D#optical_character_recognition_ocr) as it is optimized for dense text and documents.
Also, please note that services such as Cloud Vision or Document AI, are powered by Machine Learning models as such results are sometimes not quite what was expected due to being sensible to input data quality and other aspects. Nevertheless, these models are continuously being improved and results will continue to improve with time.
Added to the above, I would suggest that for any quality issues that you may find while using Cloud Vision to report it using [Google's Vision AI issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187174&template=1161261), this will allow Google to be engaged directly and continue to improve the models and therefore the services.

Comment: Will I get better results if I use a noise reduction tool ?

Comment: I noticed that the sample image you shared, is 1050x214 pixels in size, which based on [this Google document](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files) is a bit smaller than recommended to go about getting the best from Cloud Vision’s text detection features.
Image preprocessing is a good practice with regards to the large set of possible image settings that can be submitted to the API. In fact, it would be particularly important to remove as much noise as possible. Nevertheless, please remember that Vision API is powered by ML algorithms which are continuously being improved.

Comment: How to get the words of attached image in a sequence ? 

Currently some words are missing when I applied "TEXT DETECTION".

https://imgur.com/Xl96H8m

It's a PNG file.

Comment: As previously mentioned, my recommendation would be to use the [DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#optical_character_recognition_ocr) feature, it would be optimal for the image you shared which has high text density. Also, please explore different pipelines, as based on your use case, you could also benefit from [DOCUMENT AI](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/process-tables#documentai_parse_table-java), however it does require for the input to be preprocessed into pdf, gif, tiff or json format.

Comment: I am using Document AI to identify tables.

The issue is that row data is coming as a string. If a column has blank value then identification is not possible.
How to identify the blank cells ?

Comment: I believe these are two separate issues, if possible please submit a separate question to address the DOCUMENT AI output issue. For the Vision API use case, I recommend using [DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#optical_character_recognition_ocr), however the end results, while will continue to improve with time, not always will be perfect due to the Machine Learning nature of the service.

Comment: FYI, Document AI has an actively monitored tag [`[cloud-document-ai]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-document-ai)